# Was Reincarnation canon?

Tags: futurama

Was the season 6 (or 7, depending how we count) finale canonical? Stripping out the stylistic changes, were the events of the show meant to have occurred?

> Namely that Fry asked Leela to marry him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, the episode is similar to the *Anthology of Interest* episodes in that it tells segmented, non-canonical stories.  David X Cohen [explains](http://www.ugo.com/tv/futurama-david-x-cohen-interview?page=3):

> So that’s one three-parter, and the other will be a really mind-blowing one, which will either be the very last, or second to last episode we broadcast – probably the very last. It’ll be most likely presented as **a special that’s kind of outside the timeline of the series**, again being an abstract episode like the 'Anthologies of Interest,' where we will see the Futurama characters in three different animation styles. Futurama itself will be reincarnated in three different styles.

Emphasis mine.  This interview was before the episode had been completed, which is why he's speaking in the future tense, and isn't sure if it'll be the finale.

Comment: Good find! Great find!